# In how many ways we can track the sessions in servlet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

What are the different ways to track the **session** in **servlet**. Is it is possible by using hidden files ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three ways

- hidden form fields
- cookies
- url encoding.

One of the ways is to use `HttpSession` You can create session using

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

or you can use `HttpSession session = request.getSession(true)`. Both statements mean that If there is associated session with this user, then return that one or create a new session. If `false` is passed, then new session is not created.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, Wel there is no need to pass true because `request.getSession()` will create a a new session if it does not exist. Still, I've added some explanation :) Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: More details, always better. +1

Answer (score 3):

sessions can be maintained in the following ways

- hidden form field.
- cookies
- encodeURL
- session object
  have a look at here [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_session_tracking.htm)

Comment: How can you do it by attribute?

Comment: Hidden form field? How can you maintain a durable state using hidden form fields ? what about set/getAttribute request scope, application scope, page scope attributes ?

Comment: @Grzegorz why cant it be possible?set a Attribute then where ever its required use get Attribute methid

Comment: @ErhanBagdemir in a form by making hidden form field cant a value be passed?

Comment: @ErhanBagdemir according to you the above answers are also wrong

Comment: @ErhanBagdemir please have through look here http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/jspsession/SessionManagement.shtml

Comment: You can call setAttribute() and getAttribute() methods on HttpServletRequest, too. It means, you put the objects into the request scope.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi see my answer above.

Comment: @Erhan Bagdemir, I read your posts, but what is the **difference** betwheen this answer and Prasad's answer?

Comment: @ErhanBagdemir as far as i know setAttribute and getAttribute are httpsession methods see here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18206234/revisions you can read the first revision of the answer. It wasn't precisely explained on which object the get/setAttributes() methods should be called. You can also put the objects into request scope calling setAttribute on HttpServletRequest which doesn't maintain a durable state.

Comment: @javaBeginner, wrong, you have `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` in `javax.servlet.ServletRequest` interface too.

Comment: @ErhanBagdemir But in the answer i was referring to HttpSession session.setAttribute() and getAttribute();

Comment: @javaBeginner please read your the first revision of your answer so that we both save our time instead of discussing here unnecessarily

Answer (score 2):

The different ways to track session in servlet are:

1. Using the session API:
     a sample code for that is:

   ```
   //store the username object in the session-scope
   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   session.setAttribute("username",username);
   ```

   To retrieve the session attribute,use the session.getAttribute()

   ```
   Username username = (Username) session.getAttribute("username");
   ```
2. Using the cookies API:
     sample code:

   ```
   String name = request.getParameter("username");
   Cookie c = new Cookie("username",name);
   response.addCookie(c);
   ```

   It should be noted that a major disadvantage of using cookies for session management is that sometimes the client might have cookies turned off.
3. Using URL-Rewriting:
   The URL-rewriting strategy is not as transparrent as the cookie strategy.
   It could be implemented in a form as below:

   ```
   //present the form
   out.println("<form action='"+response.encodeURL("login.")+"'");
   ```
4. Hidden form field can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,it is possible with hidden fields.

And there are [other ways too](http://javapapers.com/servlet/explain-the-methods-used-for-session-tracking/)

- User authorization
- Hidden fields
- URL rewriting
- Cookies
- Session tracking API

Answer (score 0):

Session can be maintained in flowing ways

1. Hidden form field :- Use full when the form are generated dynamically
2. cookies
3. URL rewriting
4. HttpSession

The [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) depend on the cookies. It uses cookies to store the session id in client system.

Answer (score 0):

These are the ways to tracking Session

> 1.With cookies
>   2.With URL rewriting
>   3.With SSL information

For more details click [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzatz%2F51%2Fprogram%2Fsesdeci.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a servlet that implements HTTP sessions receives HTTP requests from three different clients (browsers). For each client request, the servlet must be able to determine the HTTP session to which the client request pertains. Each client request belongs to just one of the three client sessions being tracked by the servlet. Currently, the product offers three ways to track sessions:

```
With cookies
With URL rewriting
With SSL information
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various session tracking mechanisms

1. Session API
2. Cookies
3. URL Rewriting
4. Hidden Form Fields

Hidden Form Fields ->

In this case, we use hidden text-field for maintaining the state of a user.
It is just programmer's trick to remember client information.

---